# `\let\openbox\relax` doesn't work in the case of `aa.cls`

Tags: amsmath, txfonts

The journal who owns [aa.cls](http://ftp.edpsciences.org/pub/aa/aa-package.zip) asks the authors to use `\usepackage[varg]{txfonts}`. However, there is a clash between that package and `amsmath` to define `\openbox`:

```
Command \openbox already defined. \vrule\hfil}}
```

So, I just tried to shut the clash down using `\let\openbox\relax`:

```
\documentclass[onecolumn]{aa}

\let\openbox\relax
\let\proof\relax
\let\endproof\relax

\usepackage[varg]{txfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
test 
\end{document}
```

But the error isn't resolved. What is the right angle of attack to this problem?

Comment: You didn't tell what exact error you get, I guess a "control sequence already defined." So try `\let\openbox\undefined` etc. to actually make the command undefined instead of assigning the meaning of `\relax`

Comment: @siracusa: I added the exact error (`Command \openbox already defined. \vrule\hfil}}`) to the question. By the way, `\let\openbox\undefined` didn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are undefining the commands while they are undefined, you need to undefine them after they are defined the first time so

```
\documentclass[onecolumn]{aa}

\usepackage[varg]{txfonts}

\let\openbox\relax
\let\proof\relax
\let\endproof\relax


\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
test 
\end{document}
```